# watchdog service is not working because /dev/watchdog does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules, device, watchdog

There is a ITE8783 watchdog chip placed within my machine (OS *Ubuntu 14.04.1*).
The kernel module [it87](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hwmon/it87.c) supports is.
This module was not automatically loaded on startup.
So I added `it87` to /etc/modules. Now the module loads at startup.

```
it87: Found IT8783F chip at 0x290, revision 0
it87: Beeping is supported
it87 it87.656: Detected broken BIOS defaults, disabling PWM interface
```

I have recognized that there is no */dev/watchdog* device showing up.
So I [googled](http://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/howto-use-linux-watchdog/) around and create it doing `mknod /dev/watchdog c 10 130`.

Now the device appears but I think the watchdog process doesn't take magically care?
Furthermore, is there anything missing because */dev/watchdog* is not created automatically?
Should I create the device with udev or anything else?
I'm not that familiar with kernel modules, devices and watchdogs. So please give me a hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Info can be found here: http://www.sat.dundee.ac.uk/psc/watchdog/watchdog-configure.html

> If all else fails, and you have no hardware support, you can load the 'softdog' module to emulate some
>   of the capabilities in software. However, this will provide greatly reduced protection as there is
>   nothing to recover from a kernel panic, or a bad peripheral driver that blocks a software reboot.

Based on this we can conclude that your board does not have HW watchdog peripheral (or kernel does not insert appropriate module for it).

You can then fallback to softdog:

```
root@Hegel:/dev# ls /dev/watchdog
ls: cannot access /dev/watchdog: No such file or directory
root@Hegel:/dev# modprobe softdog
root@Hegel:/dev# ls /dev/watchdog
/dev/watchdog
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My board has the chip IT8783F. And if I wrote if I load `it87` manually, the log gives me a feedback that it was detected. But no device was created automatically. I will post the output of lm-sensors tomorrow.